# Scala: not enough arguments for constructor DictionaryLemmatizer

Tags: java, scala, opennlp

I've got the error

```
not enough arguments for constructor DictionaryLemmatizer: (x$1: java.io.InputStream)opennlp.tools.lemmatizer.DictionaryLemmatizer.
[error] Unspecified value parameter x$1.
[error] class SimpleLemmatizerModel(map: Map[String, Map[Char, Map[String, String]]]) extends DictionaryLemmatizer  {
[error]                            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

when building such code (`sbt assembly`)

```
import opennlp.tools.lemmatizer.DictionaryLemmatizer
import scala.io.Source

class SimpleLemmatizerModel(val map: Map[String, Map[Char, Map[String, String]]]) extends DictionaryLemmatizer {

  def lemmatize(word: String, tag: String): String =
    ( for( t <- map.get(tag); w <- t.get(word(0)) )
      yield {w.getOrElse(word, word)}
    ).getOrElse(word)

  def lemmatize(token: TaggedToken): String = lemmatize(token.token, token.tag)

  def transform(tokens: Array[TaggedToken]): Array[String] = tokens.map(lemmatize)

}
```

where

```
trait Tokens {val token: String}

trait TaggedTokens extends Tokens {val tag: String}

case class TaggedToken(token: String, tag: String) extends TaggedTokens {
  override def toString = token + ": " + tag
}

case class Token(token: String) extends Tokens {
  def tag(t: String): TaggedTokens = TaggedToken(token, t)
}
```

the `DictionaryLemmatizer` is a class of OpenNLP library written in Java and its code can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/lemmatizer/DictionaryLemmatizer.java).

I will be appreciated if somebody explain the reason of such error and how it can be fixed.

If some additional info is required, I'll gladly provide it.

Comment: Offtopic: I have a **hard** time seeing how something that takes `Map[String, Map[Char, Map[String, String]]]` deserves to have "simple" in its name ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor of `DictionaryLemmatizer` expects an argument `dictionary` of type `java.io.InputStream`.

You may want to implement [`Lemmatizer`](https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/lemmatizer/Lemmatizer.java) interface instead:

```scala
class SimpleLemmatizerModel(...) extends Lemmatizer { ... }
```

Note: you have to implement those `lemmatize` methods in order to make `SimpleLemmatizerModel` concrete.